# Address Standardization/Correction/Geocoding

Tags: geocoding, mailaddress

My place of employment is looking into buying a third party tool, for batch based US and Canadian Address correction, with Geo-coding.

- What Products have you used?
- What do you like about them?
- What do you not like about them?

Note that, We are a C/C++ Unix Shop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use [Melissa Data](http://www.melissadata.com/), they have a number of solutions including geocoding and address normalization.  They have good APIs and the support has been great.  Their solutions work on many platforms and languages including C and C++ on Unix.  Can't think anything negative about them.

Comment: it is interesting that only you and I seem to have address issues to deal with.

Comment: Apparently.  I work for a direct marketing company so work a lot with address correction and standardization.  Did you find something that worked for you?

Comment: Yes, we are using a product from IST.

Answer (score 1):

We use Trillium in our office.  They provide C# libraries that you can incorporate into your projects.  It will take an address and return a pretty complex standardized address object but does include information like geocodes (which are important for calculating tax).